# How can I execute a Windows batch file as a separate process from Java?

Tags: java, batch-file

I'm writing a class in Java which will be calling a Windows batch file.  When I run this class, the batch file is getting opened and getting closed.  How can I make the batch file continue to run after the Java program terminates?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably calling the batch with `cmd /c batch.cmd`. If you use `/k` instead of `/c` the window will stay open after the batch ran.

Answer (score 1):

See this [article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=1) for how to use Runtime.exec properly.

You probably need to start a new command line window:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
String[] commandArgs = new String[]{"cmd", "/C", "start", "c:\\test.bat" };
Process proc = rt.exec(commandArgs);
```